# How to add an ActionListener to a self defined object

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

So in my code, I was trying to create a self-defined Tile object. I wanted to place an action listener in the constructor for the Tile object, but that is where things are going wrong. I get the error `The method addActionListener(Tile) is undefined for the type Tile`. What does this error mean, and is there a way to fix it without changing to a different type of listener?

```
public class Tile extends JLabel implements ActionListener{

public Tile(int x, int y, Color c){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    setMinimumSize(size);
    setMaximumSize(size);
    setPreferredSize(size);
    setOpaque(true);
    setBackground(c);
    addActionListener(this);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    changeColor(Color.red);     
}

}
```

Comment: It means you've not defined the `addActionListener` method in the class `Title` - you need to supply both the add and remove methods and the means by which they notify registered listeners of the action. The simplest way is to write code

Comment: Take a look at the JavaDocs for [`JLabel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html), do you see any `addActionListener` methods?  This is the problem, the method is simply undefined

Answer (score 1):

While you can add your own methods to implement `ActionListener` I suspect it's probably not what you want. Depending on what event you want to respond to you will need to use different methods to add a listeneer.

For example if you want to respond to a click on the label, then you need a `MouseListener`.

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapater() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        ...
    }
});
```

There are many other versions of this depending on what you wish to respond to. I suggest you read through the tutorial chapter at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html for more examples.

Comment: It probably ought to be a `JButton` rather than a `JLabel`.

Comment: It would depend on what the op wants to - ie if they want to also use a key binding, an ActionListener would make sense

Answer (score 0):

There is no `addActionListener()` method for JLabels and your Tile class extends JLabel.  As @MadProgrammer said, you can define your own `addActionListener()` methods yourself for your Tile class if you want.